# Replace URLs with string by class or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

Newbie alert.

I am attempting to replace URLs that are currently being displayed on the page with the string "Website". It can't be all URLs, must be class-specific. Also, the URLs are each different, but they're structured (DOM) the same. Could I GetElementByID or select an individual element?

How would one go about this using JS? Many thanks for any and all suggestions!

My start:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".element span").text(function(index, text) {

    return text.replace('http://dynamic url', 'Website');

    });
});
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed a sample of the HTML, including a URL that should be changed and one that should not.

Comment: <li class="website"><span class="label">website: </span><span     class="information"><a href="http://www.uofmhealth.org/medical-    services/abnormal-heart-rhythms" title="www.uofmhealth.org/medical-    services/abnormal-heart-rhythms"     target="_blank">www.uofmhealth.org/medical-services/abnormal-heart-    rhythms</a></span></li>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create your links with class `replace-url`

```
<a href="http://someurl.com" class="replace-url">whatever</a>
```

this js would work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.replace-url').each(function() {
        this.href = 'website';
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the host of the target.

```
$(selector).prop('host', 'www.newhost.com');
```

That will keep the structure the same.  "www.host.com/sub1/index.php" would become "www.newhost.com/sub1/index.php"

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xt4gp4b/

Comment: Found it by inspecting the element in the dom just a few secs ago, :D

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of the `<a>` elements with a specific class, then change the href attribute and html, like this (jQuery):

```js
// select all of the links with the class "link"
var links = $('a[class="link"]');

// replace the link with a hash:
links.attr('href',"#");

// replace the text:
links.html("Hello World!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="link" href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a class="link" href="#bar">Bar</a>
<a class="link" href="#baz">Baz</a>
```